# Laravel custom command not working

Tags: php, laravel

I made a new command with:

```
php artisan make:console CrawlData
```

Then I changed two variables:

```
protected $signature = 'make:crawl';
protected $description = 'My crawling command';
```

The problem is that when I run:

```
php artisan make:crawl
```

It outputs:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
Command "make:crawl" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You also need to register the command in the `App\Console\Kernel` class for it to be recognized:

```
protected $commands = [
    ...
    \App\Console\Commands\CrawlData::class,
];
```

You can read more about that in the [Registering Commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#registering-commands) documentation.

---

> Starting with **Laravel 5.5** commands in `app/Console/Commands` are [automatically registered](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#registering-commands).